# Generate random connectivity between nodes in a tree

Tags: c++, graph

I need to write a program on breath first search. I have good idea about the algorithm and can implement it. I have a small problem. In my homework i have been asked to generate random connectivity among the nodes. I thought generate a random number between 0 and all edges possible which will represent the total number of edges. Then for each one of those edges, you will randomly select two nodes. but this doesn't sound good. Need help

Comment: What's wrong with just taking a random subset of the group of all possible edges?

Comment: i dont think that will work.

Comment: Please explain what your criteria for deciding that an approach "doesn't sound good" or "will not work" is; @BenjaminGreunbaum's suggestion WILL generate random connectivity, but (apparently) you have other constraints.

Comment: If you have already a tree then any additional edge will introduce a loop. Therefore, I assume that the extended graph is not a tree. (Right?) If n is the number of nodes then n*(n-1)/2-(n-1) is the number of possible distinct additional non-oriented edges. This number grows with the square of the number of nodes. Maybe, this is bad. But, you could choose a random node and then a second random node out of the n-1 remaining other nodes. Look whether this edge does not yet exist. If it exists try again else add the new edge.

Comment: Just one comment to my previous comment. The difference in the growth of the number of possible edges (O(n^2)) and the number of edges in the tree (n-1) makes the alorithm efficient for large n if the number of added eddges keeps small. If the number of added edges is in the same order of magnitude as the number of maximal possible edges the algorithm performs bad since the search for new node pairs will fail more often.

Comment: Sorry but having random set makes it too complicated